# Add dynamic footer to the TWIG file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twig

I need to get data from one of my php file (basically I have written mysql query there) and I want to display that in TWIG file(parent.html)

Here is the code for more information.
This is parent.html and I need to include footer in this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEAM Aero: Your Commercial Jet Aircraft Trading Community</title>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta name="description" content="TEAM Aero: Your Commercial Jet Aircraft Trading Community" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/css/grid-menu-style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/css/grid-menu-style-responsive.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/libs/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/js/libs/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    {% block extra_js %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>

<div class='header'>
    <div class="clearfix">

        <div style="float: left;">
            <a href="/controls/grid_menu/view.php">
                <img src="/images/grid_menu/biglogo.jpg" style="float:right;"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right-block">
            {% if globals.user.id %}
                <div class="header-image-wrapper">
                {% if globals.user.image %}
                    <img src="/files/user_photos/{{ globals.user.image }}" style="max-height: 100px; max-width: 100px;">
                {% else %}
                    <img src="/images/icon_no_photo_80x80.png" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">
                {% endif %}
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <a href="/auth/login.php">
                    <div class="header-login-wrapper">
                        <div class="header-right-block-text">LOG IN</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width:97%;margin: auto;padding-top:15px;">
    <a href="http://www.pw.utc.com/DependableServices" target="_blank">
        <img src="/images/grid_menu/PW-Services_Distance_600x100.jpg" style="width:100%;text-align:center;">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="user-info" data-role-id="{{ globals.role_id }}"></div>

<div class="free-wall grid-menu-container">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>

{% include "grid_menu/footer.html" %}
</body>
</html>
```

The below code is footer.php that include query

```
<?php

require_once("../../bootstrap.php");

$menus = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from("GridMenu")
    ->where("position = ?", array(12))
    ->orwhere("position = ?", array(11))
    ->orwhere("position = ?", array(10))
    ->orderBy("position ASC")
    ->execute();

$menusMap = array();
foreach($menus as $menu){
    if(empty($menusMap[$menu->position])){
        $menusMap[$menu->position] = array();
    }
    $menusMap[$menu->position][] = $menu;
}


foreach($menusMap as $menuPosition => $menusArray) {

    if($menuPosition == 0){

        continue;
    }
    //shuffle($menusArray);
    $menu = $menusArray[0];

    $block[$menuPosition]['image_path']= $menu->image_path;
    $block[$menuPosition]['url']= $menu->url;
} 
echo $twig->render('grid_menu/footer.html', array(
    "user" => User::getCurrent(),
    "menusMaps" => $block
));

?>
```

This is footer.html that is written in twig

```
{% block footer %}

<div class='footerAd'>
{% for key, menusMap in menusMaps %}
<a href='{{ menusMap.url|e }}' target='_self'><div class='cell' style='background-image: url(/images/grid_menu/{{ menusMap.image_path|e }});background-size:100% 100%;float:left;position:relative;margin:20px'></div></a>
{% endfor %}
</div>


<div class='header' style="clear:both">
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="float-left">

            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

In result parent.html is not showing database result, I want to display footer content in parent.html, although it is showing div but not the query result.

I am very new in TWIG, you little help can solve the big issue for me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your code is "*showing div but not query result*". This means that `{% include "grid_menu/footer.html" %}` is indeed accessing to the `grid_menu/footer.html`. The query result is not showing because you haven't yet executed the query. All you have done is including the `footer.html`, but in no place you execute the `footer.php`.

If you are using Symfony, this could be automatic by implementing what it is called [embedded controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers). From your code structure, I assume you are not using Symfony. Never mind!

I'll give you a very simple solution, trying not to change too much code. The main problem you have here is because of `{% include "grid_menu/footer.html" %}`. Normally, you should include the `footer.php` but this is not allowed by twig unless you use a twig extension like e.g a function:

```
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction("render", function ($phpFile) {
   include $phpFile;
}, array('is_safe' => array('html')));

$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Now with this function "`render`" defined, you can use:

```
{{ render("footer.php") }}
```

instead of:

```
{% include "grid_menu/footer.html" %}
```

Allow me to remark on something nothing to do with the question, but I couldn't bring myself not to say it: Instead of using positional parameters, you can use `whereIn` function, like following:

```
$menus = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from("GridMenu")
    ->whereIn("position", array(10, 11, 12))
    ->orderBy("position ASC")
    ->execute();
```

If you get stuck on some step, please let me know. I'll be very pleased to help.

Hope it's useful!

Comment: HI, Thanks a lot!
But can you please tell me..Where should I add that twig extension, also what is $phpFile referring her?

Comment: Yes, I am new for doctrine also..Thanks for help! :)

Comment: @PHP: My pleasure :) $phpFile is referring to the php file you want to render. The name of the twig extension is "render", and it is a function that admits one parameter $phpFile. When you do {{ render("footer.php") }} you are calling the twig extension function "render" and you are passing "footer.php" as a parameter.

Comment: @PHP: You can add the twig extension in the same file your have included the twig library. If you still get stuck on this step, please post here the hierarchy of your files, and where you have included the twig library and I'll show in detail.